# Load balancer at home with 2 ISP

Tags: networking, router, vlan, wan, load-balancer

I have 2 floor house and 2 ISPs. One is via  wireless and the secondary is LTE. One router can only go on the first floor, as the Wifi connection antenna end is placed there, and second (LTE) can be placed on second floor where it receives the best bandwidth from the LTE ISP (Orange).

I need to setup load balancer on TP-Link TL-R470T.

Can you please take a look at the picture and tell me whether my idea is realistic and manageable using these devices? The TL-SG105E switches are only suggestion but I have the TL-R470T already.

[image: See my plan]

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? In general, any form of aggregation or failover requires one gateway to be 'in charge' & be able to see & control both WAN connections.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve Internet from 2 ISP. This could be handle by router TP-Link TL-R470T. This router will decide how traffic will be distributed among LAN desktops (vlan2). Unfortunately between floors I have a single ethernet cable. I thought that I could use a single ethernet cable to perform traffic between desktops to router TL-470T and simultaneously on the same cable I could use WAN port1 to connect to router Huawei B525 by using separate vlan1.